# How to check if balls in a list collide, and remove them from list

Tags: python, list, class, simulation

So I have a Ball class that looks like this:

```
   class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self,n,x0,y0,dx,dy,r,c):
        self.xc = x0
        self.yc = y0
        self.dx = dx
        self.dy = dy
        self.radius = r
        self.area = math.pi*((r)**2)
        self.color = c
        self.name = n
    def position(self):
        return (self.xc,self.yc)
    def move(self):
        self.xc+=self.dx
        self.yc+=self.dy
    def collide(self,o,new_name):
        x = ((self.area*self.xc)+(o.area*o.xc))/(self.area+o.area)
        y = ((self.area*self.yc)+(o.area*o.yc))/(self.area+o.area)
        dx = ((self.area*self.dx)+(o.area*o.dx))/(self.area+o.area)
        dy = ((self.area*self.dy)+(o.area*o.dy))/(self.area+o.area)
        if self.area >= o.area:
            c = self.color
        else:
            c = o.color
        area = (self.area+o.area)
        r = math.sqrt(area/(math.pi))
        return Ball(new_name,x,y,dx,dy,r,c)
    def does_collide(self,o):
        if math.hypot((self.xc-o.xc),(self.yc-o.yc))<=(self.radius+o.radius):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And I'm running a while loop in my main code to simulate various balls, each ball moving by its dx and dy value each iteration. To do this, I have a list called balls that holds all my ball objects. It looks something like this:

```
    balls=[ball1,ball2,ball3,ball4...] and so forth
```

What I want to do is use the does_collide function in my ball class to check if two balls collide, and if they do I want to delete the two balls from the list and insert a new ball in the list, created by the collide function. The collide function creates a new ball whose x, y, dx, and dy values are the weighted averages of the two balls and whose color is the color of the biggest ball.

**So for all the balls in my list, how do I actively check if any two balls have collided using the does_collide function and remove them from the list? I also want to add the new ball to the list, the result of the collide function.**

I tried doing something like this:

```
         for ball1 in balls:
            for ball2 in balls:
                if ball1.name!=ball2.name:
                    if ball1.does_collide(ball2) == True:
                        ball = ball1.collide(ball2,(int(N)+1))
                        balls.append(ball)
                        balls.remove(ball1)
                        balls.remove(ball2)
```

but that just seems to be very messy and crashes every time a collision occurs.

Comment: `itertools.combinations` could produce 2-tuples to compare and save you some nested loops.

Comment: You're modifying the list you're iterating over which is never a good idea.

Comment: Just a little note: try to quickly read the [Zen of Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#the-zen-of-python-1), which is a wonderful guide to producing clean and Pythonic code. I don't know if you come from Lisp-y languages, but heck, you use a lot of unnecessary parentheses!:)

Comment: These look more like C-heritage excessive parentheses than Lisp-heritage… but yeah, either way, excessive parentheses always make the code harder to read.

Comment: Meanwhile… do you actually need to modify `balls` in-place, instead of just building a new filtered `balls` to replace the old one?

Comment: @whatyouhide: I undid your changes to the question because I thought they were out-of-line. Post an answer if you want to rewrite the OP's code (even if it doesn't answer their question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you care about ordering? If not, here's one way you could do it.

```
import itertools

newballs = []
removed = set()
for b1, b2 in itertools.combinations(balls, 2):
    if b1 not in removed and b2 not in removed:
        if b1.does_collide(b2):
            removed.add(b1)
            removed.add(b2)
            newballs.append(b1.collide(b2))

balls = [b for b in balls if b not in removed] + newballs
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your outer loop run over the whole list, but let you inner loop only run from the current outer loop ball+1 to the end of the list.  Clearly, if ball 5 (for example) collides with ball 8 (for example), then ball 8 collides with ball 5, so you don't have to check both.

Also, you are removing items from the list *at the same time that you are iterating over the list*.  This can't be safe.  Instead of doing the removal inside the loop, I would just set flags inside the loop indicating which balls should be removed, and then remove them in another loop.

Comment: Personally I find it a lot simpler and clearer to just iterate over a copy of the array instead. It also saves some bookkeeping.